# BeautifulSoup to extract csv data from website

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have used beautiful soup4 to get the following from the command

```
print(soup.prettify)
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>
       Euro Millions Winning Numbers
      </title>
      <body>
       <pre> Euro Millions Winning Numbers

    No., Day,DD,MMM,YYYY, N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2,  Jackpot,   Wins
    759, Tue,30,Dec,2014, 06,18,39,44,50,08,11,  11727000,    1
    708, Fri, 4,Jul,2014, 04,18,39,43,47,02,06,  33347512,    0
   <hr><b>All lotteries below have exceeded the 180 days expiry date</b><hr>No.,       Day,DD,MMM,YYYY, N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2,  Jackpot,   Wins
    707, Tue, 1,Jul,2014, 18,22,25,27,39,05,10,  25344616,    0
       1, Fri,13,Feb,2004, 16,29,32,36,41,07,09,  10143000,    1

This page shows all the draws that used any machine and any ball set in any year.

Data obtained from http://lottery.merseyworld.com/Euro/
</hr></hr></pre>
  </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

I don't understand how I extract from the above only the cvs data i.e..

```
No., Day,DD,MMM,YYYY, N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2,  Jackpot,   Wins
759, Tue,30,Dec,2014, 06,18,39,44,50,08,11,  11727000,    1
708, Fri, 4,Jul,2014, 04,18,39,43,47,02,06,  33347512,    0
1,   Fri,13,Feb,2004, 16,29,32,36,41,07,09,  10143000,    1
```

Can this be done using bs4 or does one have to resort to other strategies? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Ah! The reason for looking at this is to devise the 'best' way to extract data from poorly constructed csv files as this one, as downloaded from the web, is.

Comment: You will have to parse `soup.findAll('pre')` yourself I'm afraid…

Comment: Thanks! Still better than trying read.cv which doesn't work at all ( gives one long column of data) because of tabs, spaces and commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to find the `pre` tag and extract all text nodes from it. Then, split each text node by new-line and get rid of anything not starting with `No.` or a digit:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
your HTML here
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

data = soup.pre.find_all(text=True)
for row in data:
    row = row.split('\n')
    for item in row:
        item = item.strip()
        if item and (item.startswith('No.') or item[0].isdigit()):
            print item
```

Prints:

```
No., Day,DD,MMM,YYYY, N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2,  Jackpot,   Wins
759, Tue,30,Dec,2014, 06,18,39,44,50,08,11,  11727000,    1
708, Fri, 4,Jul,2014, 04,18,39,43,47,02,06,  33347512,    0
No.,       Day,DD,MMM,YYYY, N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2,  Jackpot,   Wins
707, Tue, 1,Jul,2014, 18,22,25,27,39,05,10,  25344616,    0
1, Fri,13,Feb,2004, 16,29,32,36,41,07,09,  10143000,    1
```